# Why is the shear force of simple beam "half-positive" and "half-negative"?

Tags: structural-beam

Why is the shear force of simple beam "half-positive" and "half-negative"?

As given here:

[image]

Perhaps it's because the forces have to sum somehow?

But does it make empirical sense that the force directions are different?

If the force acts on the center, then the ends would have the same forces, no?

Comment: Symmetry across the beam.

Comment: @JonCuster Yes, but if the both ends bend to the same direction, then why are their forces opposites?

Answer (score 1):

> Perhaps it's because the forces have to sum somehow?

Yes, the sum of the external forces and the internal shearing force have to equal zero at each cross section of the beam for equilibrium. (The sum of the moments also have to be equal to zero, but we won't get into that here).

See free body diagrams below.

The top is a free body diagram of a section of the beam to the left of the external applied force. It assumes there is an external downward force F acting at the center of the beam. Each support then has an upward reaction of 1/2 F.  For the section to be in equilibrium, the sum of the vertical forces on the section has to be zero.  That requires an equal downward internal shear force of 1/2 F is. An internal bending moment is also needed (magnitude not show). This free body diagram applies for all sections to the left of the applied force. The left side is said to be in positive shear.

The bottom is a free body diagram that applies to all sections to the right of the external applied force. Note that in order for equilibrium to occur with the downward external force applied to the section, the direction of the shearing force has to be the reverse of that on the left side of the beam for the sum of the vertical forces on the section to be zero. We now have negative shear. This accounts for the abrupt change in your shear diagram from positive to negative.

The choice of the terms "positive" and "negative" shear and bending moment are arbitrary. The convention for positive shear and bending moment is given in my diagram. In terms of bending, one way to remember is that "positive" bending results in a "smile" while "negative" bending results in a "frown".

Hope this helps.

[image]